# How to refresh reCaptcha image using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, captcha, recaptcha

As per my title, how do i refresh the recaptcha image FOR Google's recaptcha plugin in php. Is it possible?

I realise there isn't a 2nd try for the plugin of the same image so my take was that everytime the user enter and fails, i will need to refresh the image using jquery.

I don't want and do not need to refresh the page because i'm using .post to do the checking of the captcha input.

Following is my Javascript code.

```
        if($("input[name='recaptcha_response_field']").val().length<=0){
            formOkay=0;
            alert('Captcha helps prevent Spamming. Captcha Cannot be empty');
            return false;          
        }else{
            $.post('/external_scripts/recaptcha-php-1.11/jpost/verification.php',$("form[name='registration']").serialize(),function(data){
                if(data==0){
                    formOkay=0;
                    alert('Captcha is Wrong');
                    return false;
                }else{
                    ..CARRY ON WITH FORM SUBMISSION
```

Comment: have u tried Recaptcha.reload(); ?

Comment: Great! you want to submit an answer? I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Recaptcha.reload
```

The method `reload` displays a new CAPTCHA challenge  **[Docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization)**